# Should I use 'They' or 'These' here?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, pronouns, demonstratives

It's a test question from my daughter's English teacher. Here is the question.

> There are some other things for her birthday. ____ are apples, bananas and some toys.
>
> A. They   B. These   C. That

I thinks the answer should be 'These', but the teacher said 'They' is correct. Is it wrong to use 'These' here? What's the difference?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on whether 'there' is locative or existential in the first sentence, Perhaps you could ask your teacher?

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. 'They' is the correct answer because in the context, 'They' means 'other things'.

Comment: Well, *these* also works. Have you looked up *they* and *these* in a dictionary? Anyway, I think your question is offtopic on this site, because this site is not meant for people learning English. You should this question on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com).